# Winter Bash Snaphat Hat

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

I have a doubt, I just received the Snaphat hat for a question that was made 2 days ago and I answered two days ago, but until today I have not had more than 3 votes and it has been accepted today.

My question is: should the answer be accepted within 30 minutes of the question being asked? Or is it a bug that has happened to me?

Comment: It can be accepted at any time